# celeryd and celerybeat - "Received unregistered task of type..."

Tags: python, celery, daemon, celerybeat

OK guys, this is driving me nuts. I've been working on this for a FULL DAY now, and can't get it to work!
My celery project structure is this:

```
# celery.py

from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('scheduler.celery',
                include=['scheduler.tasks'])

celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
```

And:

```
# tasks.py

from scheduler.celery import celery

@celery.task
def test():
    do_something()
```

And:

```
# celeryconfig.py

from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'test-cron': {
        'task': 'tasks.test',
         'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
    },
}
# CELERY_IMPORTS = ('tasks', )
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

All files are under `projects/scheduler/` folder.
When I start the `celeryd` service I can see it's running and connecting to my broker, but when I start the `celerybeat` service, I can see in the log the message: `Received unregistered task of type 'tasks.test'`.
If I uncomment the `CELERY_IMPORTS` constant (as suggested in many answers here in SO), the `celeryd` service won't even start! Actually, it outputs `OK` but using `ps ef | grep celery` I can see it's not running.

My daemon conf file looks like this:

```
# Name of nodes to start
CELERYD_NODES="w1"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/me/projects/scheduler/"

# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=4"

# %n will be replaced with the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"

# Extra arguments to celerybeat
CELERYBEAT_OPTS="--schedule=/var/run/celerybeat-schedule"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have `scheduler` module and run celery from module root:

**`runner.py`**:

```
from celery_test import celery

if __name__ == '__main__':
    celery.start()
```

renamed **`celery.py`** to **`celery_test.py`**:

```
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('scheduler.celery',
                include=['tasks'])

celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
```

**`celeryconfig.py`**:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'test-cron': {
        'task': 'tasks.test',
         'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
    },
}

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

**`tasks.py`**, fixed import:

```
from celery_test import celery

@celery.task
def test():
    do_something()
```

There are you must be careful with imports and add `runner.py` because it import `celery_test` and then `tasks` inside which importing `celery_test` again.

---

If you have `scheduler` module and run celery from module root:

**`__init__.py`** empty.

**`runner.py`**:

```
from scheduler.celery_test import celery

if __name__ == '__main__':
    celery.start()
```

renamed **`celery.py`** to **`celery_test.py`**:

```
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('scheduler.celery',
                include=['scheduler.tasks'])

celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
```

**`celeryconfig.py`**, fixed default task name:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'test-cron': {
        'task': 'scheduler.tasks.test',
         'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
    },
}

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

**`tasks.py`**:

```
from scheduler.celery_test import celery

@celery.task
def test():
    do_something()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It didn't work on our machine. I finally made it work moving by `celeryconfig.py` outside the `scheduler` folder. Not ideal, but at least it works

Comment: Did you try load config as `celery.config_from_object('scheduler.celeryconfig')` instead moving file?

Comment: No, I thought that the `CELERYD_CHDIR` should be enough for the pointing to the path of the file.